# Move Grid save and cancel buttons from far right, maybe left justify

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

Is there a way in Vaadin 7 or Vaadin 8 to move the save/cancel buttons to under the last editor column?  Or maybe to left justify them?  Right now they are right justified under the last column.  I would even take left justifying them under this same column.  Visually, it is far from the last thing the users edited, so some users get confused.  The way I am clarifying it for users right now is by making the Grid as narrow as possible, but it wastes screen real estate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be very difficult in generic case, where column widths can be freely adjusted or their widths are automatically calculated by content. However if you set your columns fixed widths, so that you can make assumptions based on that within your specific application, there is a solution.

Just noting, that the `Editor` has `div`, with class name "`v-grid-editor-footer`", which has the same width as the `Grid`. So the editor footer does not have logical cells, that would be aligned with `Grid`'s cells. And that is the challenge here. Furthermore the buttons you are refering to are wrapped in a child `div` of the previous one, with class name "`v-grid-editor-buttons`"

However you can try to add css rules in your theme in the following way.

```
.v-grid-editor-buttons {
    position: relative;
    left: -300px; // Adjust this value experimentally so that it fits your need
}
```

Below is a screenshot the css applied to Vaadin's Sampler.

[image]